# Multi-Desktop AMD HD6870 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, ati

I'm currently trying to set my monitor up as Multi-Desktop.
Ive got two monitors, a 1920x1080(1) and 1280x1024(2). The problem is that im getting a normal desktop on one of the screens, while the other one is blank(grey) with a cross as cursor. Which display getting gray seems to be the one placed to the left in amdcccle.

Ive tried enabling xinerama, which gives me a desktop on both monitors, but unity doesn't appear.

Im using the newest amd-drivers(12.4).

1 is connected with hdmi

2 with dvi

Heres my xorg.conf: http://pastebin.com/K7U8XmuT

Can anyone help me out? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with two Radeon HD3450 cards on four monitors.

I was able to get things working by choosing Unity2D (not 3D) on login and enabling Xinerama. I have four monitors and it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use xinerama?
Your card should have some kind of linux driver. Try their website, or see if ubuntu has any additional drivers on board.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make do with the free drivers (not Catalyst) - i.e. you don't need to play new games and power consumption is not that big of an issue - you should try removing the proprietary driver using System Settings -> Additional drivers.

With the free drivers multi-monitor has pretty much always just worked for me.